# What am I doing wrong in finding set intersection between two sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have two sets:

Universal set, U = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}

A = {2,3,5}, sum of A, n(A) = 2+3+5 = 10

B = {1,2,3,7}, sum of A, n(B) = 1+2+3+7 = 13

Intersection sum between A & B = $$( n(A)+n(B)) - (n(A)-n(B)) + (n(A)-n(B) )$$

$$ = n(A)+n(B) - n(A)+n(B) + n(A)-n(B)$$
$$ = n(A)+n(B) $$

But $n(A)+n(B)$ includes the intersection twice. How can I fix it to calculate the sum intersection between the two given sets ?

Comment: I don't understand your calculation.  You can't compute $n(A\cap B)$ simply from $n(A),n(B)$.  For instance, given $n(A)=3=n(B)$ we might have $A=(1,2),B=(3)$ or $A=(3)=B$.

Comment: See [Inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: Got my mistake. Sum cannot be the metric to obtain to check for any intersection. I was using this technique to check if any pair of sets covers the Universal set. Is there any other proper way to check if two sets cover the universal set without explicitly checking element by element every time for every pair of sets ? (Given L subsets of the Universal set U = {1,2,3,4,...., m}). My current approach is O(n3)